# Picasso load image in arraylist hashmap using mysql url

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, picasso

**Question:**

I want to convert my image URL to an image using Picasso.

**Explained:**

Using a JSON query, the data is received from the database. The data is containing an URL which I want to convert to an image (preferably using Picasso).

**What it does now:**

All the data is being put in an ArrayList. When retrieving the data, all data shows exept the image (using ImageView in the XML).

**What I tried**

Put all the Picasso options everywhere, but I don't know how I can use Picasso in an ArrayList or HashMap.

**The code**

Here the piece of the code I want to implement this. If more is needed, I will add more.

Piece of code before OnCreate

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipesList;
```

Piece of code loading the list

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    recipesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading ingredients in Background Thread
    new LoadAllRecipes().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
```

Piece of code retrieving the information, including a Picasso tag

```
if (success == 1) {
    // recipies found
    // Getting Array of Ingredients
    recipes = json.getJSONArray(TAG_recipes);

    // looping through all recipes
    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = recipes.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String photo = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);
    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);

    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
    Picasso.get().load(map.put( TAG_PHOTO, photo ));

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    recipesList.add(map);

    }
```

The adapter at the bottom

```
  /**
  * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
  * */
 ListAdapter adapter;
 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
      ActivityTwo.this, recipesList,
      R.layout.activity_two_details_cards, new String[] { TAG_PID,
      TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_TIME, TAG_PHOTO},
      new int [] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.time, R.id.imagePhoto});// updating listview
      setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because map.put return

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no
>   mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports
>   null values.)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)

In your example previous map value for specific key is null. You can fix you code as

```
...
map.put(TAG_PHOTO, photo);
Picasso.get().load(map.get(TAG_PHOTO));
...
```

Comment: Thank for this, but it didn't solve the problem. Error out of logcat: W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://...

Comment: @Koetjeboe Do you debug your app on real device?

Comment: I use a virtual device. I will port it to my phone as well. EDIT: No, no image on real device as well.

Comment: @Koetjeboe try to open your image http://.. via internet browser from devices for check accessibility. It looks like a problem not in picasso

Comment: The picture is working perfectly. On an other tab (when the recipe is clicked) picasso loads the image perfect (normal page, not a arraylist)

Comment: Do you have any idea left please?